# Dialog box program, the blue font found after tenth option, "Is there a shortcut key or keybindings to those options?"

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, dialog

I used dialog to create a menu that logs time with time warrior commands.  My question is about the dialog script, first time I used it, here is what my script looks like.

[image]

My question is there keybindings for the options like say, option 12.  What do the blue font indicate to me as a user?

I have installed it on Ubuntu server:

- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Release:        18.04
- Codename:       bionic

```
$ dialog --version
Version: 1.3-20171209
```

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: @JoelDerouchey I suppose that pressing `1` four times will move you to the `12`.

Comment: @K7AAY your great welcome text may confuse users, make it shorter and reasonable, please.

Comment: I verify that pressing 1 four times, works.  However looking at the menu, just thinking the blue font meant some type of functionality, but skimming the documentation, and experimenting with key strokes did not discovered the meaning to the blue font.  Its a small matter, but just thought I could figure this out by now.  :-)